# Local variable 'state' value is not used

Tags: python

I don't understand why my variable is not recognized in my function and why it is not updated after the function is executed. I have applied the same procedure throughout my project and it has worked every time. Here is my code:

```
all_button = []
state = "normal"

for x in range(5):
    all_button.append(tk.Button(new_scrollable_frame, text=str(x)))

def show_or_destroy_3d(state_3d):

    def hide():
        print("Destroy")
        for i in all_button:
            i.destroy()

    def show():
        print("Show")
        for i in all_button:
            i.pack(side="left")

    if state_3d == "normal":
        state = "destroyed" # don't work
        hide()

    else:
        state = "normal" # don't work
        show()

tk.Button(new_scrollable_frame, height=3, width=10, text="Fichier 3D",
          command=lambda test=state: show_or_destroy_3d(test)).pack(side="left")
```

I tried to replace the 2 "state =" by state.replace() but it doesn't change anything.. I tried many other thing but nothing worked. Surely a basic mistake, if someone could help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `global` keyword:

```py
def show_or_destroy_3d(state_3d):
    global state
    # ...
```